# Ember 2.16.x: Accessing Ember.Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression with new import syntax

Tags: windows, ember.js

How does one access the `Ember.Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression` function using the new import syntax in Ember 2.16.x and above?

The following code snippet comes from the [**Writing Helpers** section of the Ember docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_escaping-html-content). (FYI, there are a couple of unrelated errors in the original, which I have cleaned up in the code below.)

```js
import { helper } from "@ember/component/helper";
import Handlebars from "handlebars";
import { htmlSafe } from "@ember/string";

export function makeBold(param /*, ...rest*/ ) {
  let value = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(param);
  return htmlSafe(`<b>${value}</b>`);
}

export default helper(makeBold);
```

If I use the code above, I get the following error:

> Could not find module 'handlebars' imported from 'ember-app/helpers/make-bold'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now the `Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression` function is not yet exported by the New Module Imports (aka. RFC 176). You should keep using it from the `Ember` import for now:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

Ember.Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(...)
```

An open GitHub issue for this exists at https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-rfc176-data/issues/12

The guides page that you linked appears to be mistaken and we need to fix that particular snippet. Sorry about that!

Comment: Roger that. I had fallen back to that solution because it still worked, but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't "doing it wrong." Thanks!